# How to make a Variable clickable in php file

Tags: php, variables, url, hyperlink, clickable

I have a php template file created by this Front End Reset Password plugins. Here is original part of the template I would like to acheive:

```
$reset_url = som_get_lost_password_url() . "?somresetpass=true&action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login);

$message = __( 'Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:', 'frontend-reset-password' ) . "<br><br>";
$message .= sprintf( __( 'Username: %s', 'frontend-reset-password' ), $user_login ) . "<br><br>";
$message .= home_url( '/' ) . "<br><br>";
$message .= __( 'If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.', 'frontend-reset-password' ) . "<br><br>";
$message .= __( 'To reset your password, visit the following address:', 'frontend-reset-password' ) . "<br><br>";
//$message .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "\r\n";

// replace PAGE_ID with reset page ID $_GET['somresetpass']
$message .= $reset_url;
```

Here is what I try to achieve:

$reset_url = som_get_lost_password_url() . "?somresetpass=true&action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login);

```
$message = __( 'Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:', 'frontend-reset-password' ) . "<br><br>";
$message .= sprintf( __( 'Username: %s', 'frontend-reset-password' ), $user_login ) . "<br><br>";
$message .= home_url( '/' ) . "<br><br>";
$message .= __( 'If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.', 'frontend-reset-password' ) . "<br><br>";
$message .= __( 'To reset your password, visit the following address:', 'frontend-reset-password' ) . "<br><br>";
//$message .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "\r\n";

// replace PAGE_ID with reset page ID $_GET['somresetpass']
$message .= sprintf(__( '<a href="$reset_url">Reset Your Password</a>', 'frontend-reset-password' ) );
```

I have change the last line to make it URL, but it is not clickable in an email when this message is sent to users after they submit a Password Reset form.

How can I make it clickable in an email?

Comment: Your `$reset_url ` won't be parsed, since the whole string is in single quotes. Switch your quotes around so the string itself is in double quotes and the url is in single quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: anynber, many thanks. I just did what you say like this:

Answer (score 0):

many thanks, aynber. It works well; I just did what you say like this:

```
$message .= sprintf(__( "<a href='$reset_url'>Reset Your Password</a>", 'frontend-reset-password' ) );
```

May I ask another question for the same function? I try to figure out how to send the above link based on languages to users after they submit a Password Reset form. I use Polylang built-in theme, and could not separate in this way:

```
if (get_locale() == "en_US") {
//send the codes above
}
else {
//send message above in French and change this URL to: home_url()/fr/ ..?
}
```

Because the above default URL does not separate between home URL and its page; is it possible to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: You ought to ask that as another question, instead of tacking it on. I'm not sure of the answer to this.